# Do I need to define protocol in C# when set in cors host

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, node.js, .net-core

I have a little question about c#. I'm novice and actually not a developer, but I need to know one thing. In a `appsetting.json` file I have the following code:

```
  },
  "Cors": {
    "AllowedOrigins": ["localhost:4000"]
  }
```

So my question is do I need to define protocol in this place and write it like

```
  },
  "Cors": {
    "AllowedOrigins": ["http://localhost:4000"]
  }
```

Without http when I try to send some request the server responds with a 204 No content code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to include the scheme in the origin.

These two URLs have the same origin:

- `https://example.com/foo.html`
- `https://example.com/bar.html`

The following URLs have **different origins** than the previous two URLs:

- `https://example.net` – Different domain
- `https://www.example.com/foo.html` – Different subdomain
- `http://example.com/foo.html` – Different scheme
- `https://example.com:9000/foo.html` – Different port